# FileReader result returns null

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

im learning how to read a file with phonegap. i started everything from scratch. this is what i did:

1. Download and install npm
2. Install Phonegap via npm (npm install -g phonegap)
3. Install Cordova via npm (npm install -g cordova) ,this is probably unnecessary but i did it anyway
4. Create my testing app (phonegap create testfile)
5. Add android platform (phonegap platform add android)

After that i noticed that there is already cordova-plugin-file included on my plugin folder and in my config.xml, so i didn't install it (correct me if im wrong on this one)

Then, at the bottom of the index.html file, i edited it like this:

```
    .
    .
    .

    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script>
        function startFile()
        {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///storage/emulated/0/newfile.txt', readFile, fail);
        }

        function readFile(fileEntry) 
        {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) 
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) 
                {
                    var content = this.result;
                    alert("file content: " + content);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            });
        }

        function fail(e)
        {
            alert(e.code);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="read file" onclick="startFile()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Pretty much straightforward, since i just want to see how it reads the file and view it in an alert messagebox.

I have already copied the newfile.txt on my android storage, it seems like it found the file but the alert shows "file content: null"

the content of the file is just "hello world". Can somebody help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. instead of grabbing the file on resolveLocalFileSystemURL, i grabbed the directory first then fetch the file from the directoryEntry object

```
    function startFile()
    {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, readDir, fail);
        // cordova.file.externalRootDirectory = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/'
    }

    function readDir(dir)
    {
        dir.getFile("newfile.txt", {create: false},readFile,fail);
    }

    function readFile(fileEntry) 
    {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) 
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) 
            {
                var content = this.result;
                alert("file content: " + content);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }

    function fail(e)
    {
        alert(e.code);
    }
```